# Connecting to Oracle database from R using PL/SQL settings

Tags: r, oracle, plsql

I currently use PL/SQL to connect to a database, and I want to be able to do the same thing using R Studio.

I tried installing ROracle, but I got the following error:

> > ERROR: cannot find Oracle Client.
> >            Please set OCI_LIB64 to specify its location.

I don't know if I have the client installed or not, but I don't have admin privileges anyway and I'm not comfortable editing registries.

I then tried RODBC based on several other posts, but I either don't have or I don't know where to find the right information to enter. I know the database name, the username and password.

If I can use PL/SQL, does that mean that I have the Oracle client installed? If it does, would I be able to find its location in PL/SQL and then tell ROracle where to find it?

If not, is all the information I would need to connect with RODBC (or another package) available inside PL/SQL?

Comment: ROracle has pretty detailed (and complicated) [installation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL) instructions. If you're having trouble installing it, it would help to know what platform you're on and where specifically in those instructions you got stuck.

Comment: I'm using Windows. I don't have admin privileges so I can't add system variables or anything like that. Does PL/SQL require that the client is installed? If it does, then I must already have it.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be much help, my experience setting these things up on Windows is limited. I don't know how much is possible with limited admin access. There is another odbc based package called just **odbc**, but you're still on the hook for setting up the driver and dsn.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm hoping all the info I need is readily available somewhere in PL/SQL.